# How to get specific format using momentjs?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How to get the following format `2019-07-06T09:00:00.000Z` using momentjs

What I tried to do is:

```
console.log(moment().format()); // 2019-07-05T12:29:29+03:00`
```

What I need is instead of `+03:00` --> `000Z`  in dynamic way of course.

Any momentJS format supported the format above or should I do it manually?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in method [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

```js
console.log(new Date().toISOString())
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(moment().utc().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```